# How to update column from serialize to json with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

2 columns `name` and `hobby`,both are varchar(255).`hobby` is result of  `serialize(array())`  .

```
id   name    hobby
1    jack    a:2:{i:0;s:8:"swimming";i:1;s:8:"football";}
2    mary    a:2:{i:0;s:5:"music";i:1;s:2:"TV";}
```

As I updated database from mysql 5.3 to mariadb 10.2,I want to update `hobby` column to json format by `unserialize()` and `json_encode()`, then I can get:

```
id   name    hobby
1    jack    ["swimming","football"]
2    mary    ["music","TV"]
```

How to use PDO to do it?

Comment: For each row, load the data into PHP, `unserialize` it, `json_encode` it, save it back?

Comment: It should be pretty straightforward. PDO has [good online documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Let us know if you have further specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rough way:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name, hobby FROM your_table;');

while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];

    $unserialized_name = unserialize($row['name']);
    $unserialized_hobby = unserialize($row['hobby']);

    $jsonified_name = json_encode($unserialized_name);
    $jsonified_hobby = json_encode($unserialized_hobby);

    // now the actual UPDATE:
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE your_table SET name = :name, hobby = :hobby WHERE id = :id');

    $stmt->execute([
        'name' => $jsonified_name,
        'hobby' => $jsonified_hobby,
        'id' => $id,
    ]);
}
```

Assuimg everything is okay with your table, that should do the trick.