# Warning: PDO::exec(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, pdo

After [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087546/warning-pdoprepare-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064),I run below script:

```
$newrecord='{"firsttime":"19.53","secondtime":null,"sX464time":"6.25","wX1X465time":"4.14"}';//JSON
$sql='UPDATE  `'.$tablesnames[$i].'` SET `postrecords`='.$newrecord.' WHERE `id`='.$id;
//var_dump($sql) here
$update3=$pdo->exec($sql);
```

`var_dump($sql)` get result:

```
string 'UPDATE  `table651` SET `postrecords`={"firsttime":"19.53","secondtime":null,"sX464time":"6.25","wX1X465time":"4.14"} WHERE `id`=1'
```

But finally get warning:

> Warning: PDO::exec(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"firsttime":"0","secondtime":null,"sX464time":null

What's the problem?

Comment: In the other question you were told that you can't use parameters for the table name. Why did you remove the parameters for the data as well?

Comment: In that question,I know cannot use parameters in `prepare`,then I use `exec` directly.what's my mistake?

Comment: You were only supposed to remove the parameter for the table name, you can keep them for everything else.

Comment: You printed the SQL, you don't see the obvious error that you have a string with no quotes around it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because you don't have quotes around the JSON string in the SQL.

Use `bindParam()` to solve problem of missing quotes, as well as ensuring that everything is escaped properly to prevent SQL-injection.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE  `'.$tablesnames[$i].'` SET `postrecords` = :record WHERE `id`= :id');
$stmt->bindParam(':record', $newrecord);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Is the ` must to use?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Answer (score 0):

When you are using PDO or Object Orient MySQL, always [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Strings always need to be wrapped within quotes and numbers can be without quotes. And don't try to make a json, instead create an array then convert it to a json.

```
$post_records = json_encode(array(
    'firsttime'=> '19.53',
    'secondtime' => null,
    'sX464time' => '6.25',
    'wX1X465time' => '4.14'
));

$sql='UPDATE `'.$tablesnames[$i].'` SET `postrecords`="'.$newrecord.'" WHERE `id`='.$id;
```

Comment: The json data come from my `json_encode(unserialize())` data, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045230/how-to-update-column-from-serialize-to-json-with-pdo).I think it should be a `string` then I don't understand why should add `"`?

Comment: Because you are concatenating a variable instead of binding it. If you'll bind it, you would not need the quotes. But if you directly write in a string you would need it. You can see your query output, there are no quotes around your json string.